# Cross-thread when set visible for winForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to schedule a time to change the visible property of the form after 10 seconds.

```
Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith((task) => {
     this.Visible = true;
});
```

And I get an error like this
[image]

How can i solve it?

Comment: Use `this.Invoke(() => this.Visible = true)`

Comment: You should not use the Task.ContinueWith method unless you know EXACTLY what you are doing. If you used the `async/await` syntax, you would not have had this problem.

Comment: _"How can i solve it?"_ - just read the exception message